# PHP code in embed tag

Tags: php, html

I'm using `embed` tag in PHP like this:

```
echo "<embed src='images/meccaAdhan.mp3' name='guitar' id='BGS_ID'  autostart='true' loop='false' width='2' height='0'></embed>";
```

I need to add this code before images:

```
templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>
```

Please guide me how to solved it.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do and what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
echo "<embed src='templates/" . $this->template . "/images/meccaAdhan.mp3' ... >";
```

Answer (score 1):

See [PHP: Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for the different string manipulations available.

```
echo "<embed src=\"templates/{$this->template} ...
```

or

```
?><ebmed src="templates/<? echo $this->template ?> ...
```

as examples.